# Filtering out the end of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe with timestamps and there is one value that starts with a decrease, then stays 0 for a while and increases again starting the next cycle.

I would like to analyze the decreasing and stable part, but not the increasing part.

Ideally the code should check if there was a 0 in the df before, and if so any value > 0 afterwards should be excluded from the dataframe. It would also work to determine when the last value at ==0 occurs and delete all the data afterwards.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Cheers!

```
import pandas as pd

data = {

  "Period_index": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
  "Value": [9, 7, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: `df['Value'].shift(-1).sub(df['Value']).lt(0)`?

Answer (score -1):

If your data is always starting with decrease, staying 0 for a while and increasing, this should work.

```
df[:np.where(df.Value == 0)[0].max()]


Period index    Value
0       1       9
1       2       7
2       3       3
3       4       0
4       5       0
5       6       0
```

Answer (score -1):

try via `idxmax()` + `iloc`:

```
out=df.iloc[:df['Value'].eq(0).idxmax()]
#df.loc[:df['Value'].eq(0).idxmax()-1]
```

output of `out`:

```
    Period_index    Value
0   1                   9
1   2                   7
2   3                   3
```

**OR**

via `idxmax()` and `loc`:

```
out=df.loc[:df['Value'].eq(0)[::-1].idxmax()]
```

output of `out`:

```
    Period_index    Value
0   1               9
1   2               7
2   3               3
3   4               0
4   5               0
5   6               0
6   7               0
```

**OR**

If you don't want to get unconnected 0's then use `argmin()`:

```
df=df.loc[:(df['Value'].eq(0) | (~df['Value'].gt(df['Value'].shift()))).argmin()-1]
```

Comment: `idxmax()` returns index labels, so using `.iloc[]` is incorrect and only works if indexes happen to be the same as row numbers. If they don’t you’ll have a bug that’s hard to find.

Comment: @Cimbali yup in that case it will throw an error...thanks for noticing **:)**

Answer (score -1):

Literally as you say:

- check there has never been a zero with `.gt(0).cummin()` which returns True on non-zero and then the cumulative min, i.e. as soon as there is a False return only False
- or the value is zero with `.eq(0)`

```
>>> df['Value'].gt(0).cummin()
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: Value, dtype: bool
>>> df[df['Value'].gt(0).cummin() | df['Value'].eq(0)]
   Period_index  Value
0             1      9
1             2      7
2             3      3
3             4      0
4             5      0
5             6      0
6             7      0
```

If you’re afraid of getting unconnected zeros again you can pass the whole thing to `cummin()` again, i.e.:

```
(df[df['Value'].gt(0).cummin() | df['Value'].eq(0)]).cummin()
```

FWIW this is the only answer that *really* stops at the first zero:

```
>>> test = pd.Series([1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
>>> test[(test.gt(0).cummin() | test.eq(0)).cummin()]
0    1
1    0
2    0
dtype: int64
>>> test.loc[:test.eq(0).idxmax()]
0    1
1    0
dtype: int64
>>> test.loc[:test.eq(0)[::-1].idxmax()]
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
dtype: int64
```

@SeaBean’s answer is also good (or a variant thereof):

```
>>> test[test.gt(test.shift()).cumsum().eq(0)]
0    1
1    0
2    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will cut the serie when it starts growing again.
The rolling window calculates the variation and when it starts growing again we have a positive value captured by cummax

```
df[df.Value.rolling(2).apply(lambda w:w.values[1]-w.values[0]).cummax().fillna(-1)<=0]

   Period_index  Value
0             1      9
1             2      7
2             3      3
3             4      0
4             5      0
5             6      0
6             7      0
```

Comment: There are multiple sequences of increases and decreases, but I'm only interested in the ones leading to 0.